# from std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get every vector of points into a matrix like :

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> vec;
......................
for (int i ; i < vec.size();i++){
   imshow("stuff", cv::Mat(vec[i]); /// this crashes !!!
}
```

any idea how to do that? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please copy paste carefully ! The parenthesis after imshow is not closed !

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong in your copy constructor of cv::Mat, your parameter is passed by reference?

Comment: if you just wanna see them the answer is down there.

Comment: `for (int i; i <..` there's your problem, unitinialized `i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

imshow looks for a complete picture.

by casting a contour to a Mat you won't have a picture.
what you can do is: (src is your picture)

```
  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  /// Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

  Mat canny_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  /// Detect edges using canny
  Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
  /// Find contours
  findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );



  /// Draw contours

    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Mat test_image = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( test_image, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
       imshow("test",test_image);
       waitKey();
     }
```

Comment: how should I define the hierarchy the and the last parameter Point???

Comment: edited the answer with full code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
void draw_contour(cv::Mat &dst_img, const std::vector<cv::Point> &contour, const cv::Scalar &color)
{
  for (auto &point: contour)
  {
    dst_img.at<unsigned char>(point) = color;
  }
}
```

Or if you are using approximation of contours:

```
void draw_contour(cv::Mat &dst_img, const std::vector<cv::Point> &contour, const cv::Scalar &color)
{
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < contour.size(); ++i)
  {
    cv::line(dst_img, contour[i], contour[(i + 1) % contour.size(), color);
  }
}
```